# Recieving data from qwant API with python (Flask)

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I am using this "API", to my knowledge, it is just a link who returns json data. Link:
https://api.qwant.com/api/search/images?count=10&offset=1&q=stackoverflow

However when I try to access the data with;

```
import requests
import json
from flask import Flask, flash, redirect, render_template, request, session, url_for, json, jsonify

@app.route("/display")
def display():
    url = "https://api.qwant.com/api/search/images?count=10&offset=1&q=stackoverflow"
    data = requests.get(url).json()
    return data
```

I get the following error;

> simplejson.errors.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

And I can't seem to find out how to fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add user-agent before request,

```
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'My User Agent 1.0',
}

url = "https://api.qwant.com/api/search/images?count=10&offset=1&q=stackoverflow"
data = requests.get(url, headers=headers).json()
```

Comment: I worked, however I needed to jsonfy the output in Flask, thanks!

Comment: Some site block if request from BOT. So now we created request like same as from browser using User-Agent.

Answer (score 6):

You can solve your issue but using this type of URL :

```
https://api.qwant.com/api/search/web?count=10&offset=0&q=test&t=web&uiv=1
```

So it will be:

```
https://api.qwant.com/api/search/images?count=10&offset=0&q=stackoverflow&t=images&uiv=1
```

for your initial search.

It is only like this that you can get data from Qwant API. So that solve your issue. I cannot explain why we need to add these parameters because Qwant API is not documented and not open source. We can find a ref/source of this answer on https://github.com/asciimoo/searx/blob/master/searx/engines/qwant.py (as https://github.com/asciimoo/searx/issues/1365 is saying, the Qwant API changed this summer.)